# Validation Service on Controller or on Route filter - Laravel

Tags: php, validation, laravel, filter, controller

I have a UsersController that validates through a service Validator the inputs and if the validation fails the Validator throws a ValidatorException. Otherwise the Controller creates the user.

I was wondering if it is better to move the validation to a route filter even before the controller is being called and if the validation passes then the request can proceed and call the Controller's method to create the user. So if the controller is being "called" the inputs are valid and just create the user.

I am asking this to see if it possible and good aproach to separate even more the logic and the controller being responsible for one job (even although the validation is being made for a service, so the job is separated).

I followed this http://jasonlewis.me/article/laravel-advanced-validation and this http://www.slideshare.net/kirkbushell/comprehensive-validation-with-laravel-4 tutorials

**My code:**

```
Route::resource('users', 'UsersController', array('except' => array('create', 'edit')));

class UsersController extends \BaseController {

    protected $user;
    protected $response;
    protected $hasher;
    protected $validator;

    public function __construct(User $user,
        Response $response,
        \Illuminate\Hashing\BcryptHasher $hasher,
        \Inc\Services\Validation\UserRegistrationValidator $validator){

        $this->user = $user;
        $this->response = $response;
        $this->hasher = $hasher;
        $this->validator = $validator;

    }


    public function index()
    {   

        return $this->user->all();

    }



    public function store()
    {
        $input = Input::json();

        $this->validator->with($input->all())->validate();

        $this->user->create([
            'username' => $input->get('username'),
            'password' => $this->hasher->make($input->get('password'))
        ]);

    }



    public function show($id)
    {
        return $this->user->find($id);
    }



    public function update($id)
    {
        //
    }



    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $user = $this->user->find($id);
        $user->delete();
    }


}

class UserRegistrationValidator extends Validation{

    protected $rules = [
        'username' =>['required', 'min:3', 'max:50'],
        'password' =>['required', 'min:3']

    ];

}

abstract class Validation{

    protected $rules = array();
    protected $messages = array();
    protected $input = array();

    public function with(array $input){

        $this->input = $input;

        return $this;

    }

    public function validate(){

        $this->validator = Validator::make($this->input, $this->rules, $this->messages);

        if($this->validator->fails())
            throw new ValidationException($this->validator);
    }

}

class ValidationException extends Exception {

    protected $validator;

    public function __construct($validator){
        $this->validator = $validator;
    }

    public function getErrors(){

        return $this->validator->messages();
    }
}

App::error(function(Inc\Exceptions\Validation\ValidationException $exception, $code)
{
    $errorResponse = [
        'error' => $exception->getErrors()
    ];

    return Response::json($errorResponse, $statusCode = 422);
});
```

Comment: I like using observers for validation. Check out https://github.com/dwightwatson/validating